# Information on how to public a website

Tags: amazon-web-services, web

It's the first time I will be publishing a website and have no idea on how this works.

Here's a few details on what I'm trying to achieve.

I have created a sample website in nodejs and uploaded it to docker (two containers, one for nodejs and the other one for mongodb database)

Now I would like to upload this on aws but not really sure where to start and what I need to know.

In addition, I want a domain, the price is quite high for the .com domain I am looking.

My questions are as follow:

If I buy a domain, how do I hookup the domain so it's routed to the aws server where I have my website deign, logic and database, how exactly does this work?

What's the best way to buy a domain? does anyone have any experience and advice on the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: Voting to close as this has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to setup your vm and begin hosting your site w/ the custom ec2 URL, then configure the Amazon dns server (Route 53) with your domain to point at the correct vm.

***Step 1***

Get an ec2 box running (whatever size you think you'll need for traffic/storage).  When you go through the portal, you'll need to [Authorize Inbound Traffic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html).

Now you can sign into your ec2 vm, download any dependencies you'll need (npm for instance) and run your site just like you would locally in a terminal.  [Here's a sample](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html) that may help if you have trouble.

***Step 2***

You now need to the dns servers to translate the domain you owned into the ip of your ec2 vm.   You can use the [Route 53 service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html) to do this.

***Alternatives***

You can also use [Azure's App Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-how-works-readme?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service-web%2ftoc.json) to do this. It's a cloud app hosting service that's meant to help you get your app on the cloud and scale it without much trouble.  Here's a [Node.js Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started).

...And here's [the instructions on how to setup a custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name).

Comment: Thank you Daniel for the clear explanation, I am looking into this and will get back with my feedback.

Comment: I am deploying my app on docker and want to upload docker on aws. I noticed that you need some sort of license and there's a month trial. I wasn't aware of this. Does anyone have experience with this? Is it worth deploying my nodejs app on docker and then deploy docker container to aws or just deploy nodejs/mongodb straight to aws? Thanks